# What is the Other section in the instruments tool for iOS Apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, instruments

I am testing my app for `network usage`.
I don't have any other app running in the background but the tool shows something other than my app under "Other" in process consuming bandwidth.

What is it that is consuming the bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be any number of things:

- iCloud data syncing (photos, notes, etc.)
- App downloading from the App Store
- Mail downloading mail or attachment
- Safari loading a page
- Cell getting carrier info
- Downloading a system update
- Another application downloading via backgrounding